# can I use data transformers to combine fields in forms in symfony2

Tags: database, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to use Data transformers to merge (n) fields in a form into one persistable field?
If it's possible, how to do it? The cookbook only gives an example to transform one piece of data into another type, but I need to be able to dump N fields into only one for persistence. So if I'm showing 6 fields in the form, only 3 are real fields in DB table, first and second fields are to persisted as is, but the remaining 4 fields are to be store in the third table column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do it via `FormEvent::POST_SUBMIT` event.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Basically, something like this:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // entity or array
        $data = $event->getData();

        // get data directly from form
        $concatData = $form->get('non_mapped_field1_1')->getData() . ',' . $form->get('non_mapped_field1_2')->getData();

        // assumig that data is entity class
        $data->setSomeField($concatData);
    }
);
```

Comment: It seems like the Validator component also runs in `POST_SUBMIT`, so aren't you risking having this data set AFTER validations have run?

Comment: That is possible, but I believe (not 100% sure) that this happens first because event listener is being added in the earliest phase of form building.

Comment: Is there anything special to take care of, when registering this special event listener? It seems like POST_SUBMIT is never called for me (Symfony 3.3).

Comment: make sure that you registered the event on a form (not a field). And, silly enough, make sure that you submit the form (‘submit()’ or ‘handleRequest()’)